# MySQL slow after LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from csv

Tags: mysql, performance, csv, load-data-infile

I have MySQL 5.6.14 installed on Mac OS X.

After loading about 31 million rows of data into a table from a CSV file, even very simple queries on that one table now run very verrry slowly, often taking over 10 minutes to complete. Does anyone know if there's a common reason and solution to this?

The query I used to load the data was:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/CSV.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r';

Here's MySql status, in which I noticed there's a very large number for Innodb_os_log_written.

Any help with this would be much appreciated :)

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name                                 | Value       |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Aborted_clients                               | 1           |
| Aborted_connects                              | 2           |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                         | 0           |
| Binlog_cache_use                              | 0           |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use                    | 0           |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                         | 0           |
| Bytes_received                                | 242         |
| Bytes_sent                                    | 188         |
| Com_admin_commands                            | 0           |
| Com_assign_to_keycache                        | 0           |
| Com_alter_db                                  | 0           |
| Com_alter_db_upgrade                          | 0           |
| Com_alter_event                               | 0           |
| Com_alter_function                            | 0           |
| Com_alter_procedure                           | 0           |
| Com_alter_server                              | 0           |
| Com_alter_table                               | 0           |
| Com_alter_tablespace                          | 0           |
| Com_alter_user                                | 0           |
| Com_analyze                                   | 0           |
| Com_begin                                     | 0           |
| Com_binlog                                    | 0           |
| Com_call_procedure                            | 0           |
| Com_change_db                                 | 0           |
| Com_change_master                             | 0           |
| Com_check                                     | 0           |
| Com_checksum                                  | 0           |
| Com_commit                                    | 0           |
| Com_create_db                                 | 0           |
| Com_create_event                              | 0           |
| Com_create_function                           | 0           |
| Com_create_index                              | 0           |
| Com_create_procedure                          | 0           |
| Com_create_server                             | 0           |
| Com_create_table                              | 0           |
| Com_create_trigger                            | 0           |
| Com_create_udf                                | 0           |
| Com_create_user                               | 0           |
| Com_create_view                               | 0           |
| Com_dealloc_sql                               | 0           |
| Com_delete                                    | 0           |
| Com_delete_multi                              | 0           |
| Com_do                                        | 0           |
| Com_drop_db                                   | 0           |
| Com_drop_event                                | 0           |
| Com_drop_function                             | 0           |
| Com_drop_index                                | 0           |
| Com_drop_procedure                            | 0           |
| Com_drop_server                               | 0           |
| Com_drop_table                                | 0           |
| Com_drop_trigger                              | 0           |
| Com_drop_user                                 | 0           |
| Com_drop_view                                 | 0           |
| Com_empty_query                               | 0           |
| Com_execute_sql                               | 0           |
| Com_flush                                     | 0           |
| Com_get_diagnostics                           | 0           |
| Com_grant                                     | 0           |
| Com_ha_close                                  | 0           |
| Com_ha_open                                   | 0           |
| Com_ha_read                                   | 0           |
| Com_help                                      | 0           |
| Com_insert                                    | 0           |
| Com_insert_select                             | 0           |
| Com_install_plugin                            | 0           |
| Com_kill                                      | 0           |
| Com_load                                      | 0           |
| Com_lock_tables                               | 0           |
| Com_optimize                                  | 0           |
| Com_preload_keys                              | 0           |
| Com_prepare_sql                               | 0           |
| Com_purge                                     | 0           |
| Com_purge_before_date                         | 0           |
| Com_release_savepoint                         | 0           |
| Com_rename_table                              | 0           |
| Com_rename_user                               | 0           |
| Com_repair                                    | 0           |
| Com_replace                                   | 0           |
| Com_replace_select                            | 0           |
| Com_reset                                     | 0           |
| Com_resignal                                  | 0           |
| Com_revoke                                    | 0           |
| Com_revoke_all                                | 0           |
| Com_rollback                                  | 0           |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint                     | 0           |
| Com_savepoint                                 | 0           |
| Com_select                                    | 1           |
| Com_set_option                                | 0           |
| Com_signal                                    | 0           |
| Com_show_binlog_events                        | 0           |
| Com_show_binlogs                              | 0           |
| Com_show_charsets                             | 0           |
| Com_show_collations                           | 0           |
| Com_show_create_db                            | 0           |
| Com_show_create_event                         | 0           |
| Com_show_create_func                          | 0           |
| Com_show_create_proc                          | 0           |
| Com_show_create_table                         | 0           |
| Com_show_create_trigger                       | 0           |
| Com_show_databases                            | 0           |
| Com_show_engine_logs                          | 0           |
| Com_show_engine_mutex                         | 0           |
| Com_show_engine_status                        | 0           |
| Com_show_events                               | 0           |
| Com_show_errors                               | 0           |
| Com_show_fields                               | 0           |
| Com_show_function_code                        | 0           |
| Com_show_function_status                      | 0           |
| Com_show_grants                               | 0           |
| Com_show_keys                                 | 0           |
| Com_show_master_status                        | 0           |
| Com_show_open_tables                          | 0           |
| Com_show_plugins                              | 0           |
| Com_show_privileges                           | 0           |
| Com_show_procedure_code                       | 0           |
| Com_show_procedure_status                     | 0           |
| Com_show_processlist                          | 0           |
| Com_show_profile                              | 0           |
| Com_show_profiles                             | 0           |
| Com_show_relaylog_events                      | 0           |
| Com_show_slave_hosts                          | 0           |
| Com_show_slave_status                         | 0           |
| Com_show_status                               | 1           |
| Com_show_storage_engines                      | 0           |
| Com_show_table_status                         | 0           |
| Com_show_tables                               | 0           |
| Com_show_triggers                             | 0           |
| Com_show_variables                            | 0           |
| Com_show_warnings                             | 0           |
| Com_slave_start                               | 0           |
| Com_slave_stop                                | 0           |
| Com_stmt_close                                | 0           |
| Com_stmt_execute                              | 0           |
| Com_stmt_fetch                                | 0           |
| Com_stmt_prepare                              | 0           |
| Com_stmt_reprepare                            | 0           |
| Com_stmt_reset                                | 0           |
| Com_stmt_send_long_data                       | 0           |
| Com_truncate                                  | 0           |
| Com_uninstall_plugin                          | 0           |
| Com_unlock_tables                             | 0           |
| Com_update                                    | 0           |
| Com_update_multi                              | 0           |
| Com_xa_commit                                 | 0           |
| Com_xa_end                                    | 0           |
| Com_xa_prepare                                | 0           |
| Com_xa_recover                                | 0           |
| Com_xa_rollback                               | 0           |
| Com_xa_start                                  | 0           |
| Compression                                   | OFF         |
| Connection_errors_accept                      | 0           |
| Connection_errors_internal                    | 0           |
| Connection_errors_max_connections             | 0           |
| Connection_errors_peer_address                | 0           |
| Connection_errors_select                      | 0           |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap                     | 0           |
| Connections                                   | 400         |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                       | 0           |
| Created_tmp_files                             | 14          |
| Created_tmp_tables                            | 0           |
| Delayed_errors                                | 0           |
| Delayed_insert_threads                        | 0           |
| Delayed_writes                                | 0           |
| Flush_commands                                | 1           |
| Handler_commit                                | 0           |
| Handler_delete                                | 0           |
| Handler_discover                              | 0           |
| Handler_external_lock                         | 0           |
| Handler_mrr_init                              | 0           |
| Handler_prepare                               | 0           |
| Handler_read_first                            | 0           |
| Handler_read_key                              | 0           |
| Handler_read_last                             | 0           |
| Handler_read_next                             | 0           |
| Handler_read_prev                             | 0           |
| Handler_read_rnd                              | 0           |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                         | 0           |
| Handler_rollback                              | 0           |
| Handler_savepoint                             | 0           |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback                    | 0           |
| Handler_update                                | 0           |
| Handler_write                                 | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status                | not started |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status                | not started |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data                 | 7166        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data                 | 117407744   |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty                | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty                | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed              | 808311      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free                 | 1024        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc                 | 1           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total                | 8191        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd             | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead                 | 27550       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted         | 4676        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests              | 151824467   |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                      | 1676781     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free                  | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests             | 63323385    |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                            | 34787       |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs                    | 0           |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                     | 0           |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes                    | 0           |
| Innodb_data_read                              | 27925942272 |
| Innodb_data_reads                             | 1677284     |
| Innodb_data_writes                            | 521578      |
| Innodb_data_written                           | 31244395520 |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written                    | 808311      |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                           | 10752       |
| Innodb_have_atomic_builtins                   | ON          |
| Innodb_log_waits                              | 1           |
| Innodb_log_write_requests                     | 10773957    |
| Innodb_log_writes                             | 10161       |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                          | 10824       |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs                  | 0           |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes                  | 0           |
| Innodb_os_log_written                         | 4757200384  |
| Innodb_page_size                              | 16384       |
| Innodb_pages_created                          | 260255      |
| Innodb_pages_read                             | 1704330     |
| Innodb_pages_written                          | 808311      |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits                 | 0           |
| Innodb_row_lock_time                          | 0           |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                      | 0           |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                      | 0           |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                         | 0           |
| Innodb_rows_deleted                           | 12          |
| Innodb_rows_inserted                          | 30270085    |
| Innodb_rows_read                              | 197857232   |
| Innodb_rows_updated                           | 0           |
| Innodb_num_open_files                         | 7           |
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes                | 0           |
| Innodb_available_undo_logs                    | 128         |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                        | 0           |
| Key_blocks_unused                             | 6698        |
| Key_blocks_used                               | 0           |
| Key_read_requests                             | 0           |
| Key_reads                                     | 0           |
| Key_write_requests                            | 0           |
| Key_writes                                    | 0           |
| Last_query_cost                               | 0.000000    |
| Last_query_partial_plans                      | 0           |
| Max_used_connections                          | 3           |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                      | 0           |
| Open_files                                    | 18          |
| Open_streams                                  | 0           |
| Open_table_definitions                        | 68          |
| Open_tables                                   | 64          |
| Opened_files                                  | 1034        |
| Opened_table_definitions                      | 0           |
| Opened_tables                                 | 0           |
| Performance_schema_accounts_lost              | 0           |
| Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost          | 0           |
| Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost        | 0           |
| Performance_schema_digest_lost                | 0           |
| Performance_schema_file_classes_lost          | 0           |
| Performance_schema_file_handles_lost          | 0           |
| Performance_schema_file_instances_lost        | 0           |
| Performance_schema_hosts_lost                 | 0           |
| Performance_schema_locker_lost                | 0           |
| Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost         | 0           |
| Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost       | 0           |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost        | 0           |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost      | 0           |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost | 0           |
| Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost        | 0           |
| Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost      | 0           |
| Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost         | 0           |
| Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost     | 0           |
| Performance_schema_table_handles_lost         | 0           |
| Performance_schema_table_instances_lost       | 0           |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost        | 0           |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost      | 0           |
| Performance_schema_users_lost                 | 0           |
| Prepared_stmt_count                           | 0           |
| Qcache_free_blocks                            | 1           |
| Qcache_free_memory                            | 1031352     |
| Qcache_hits                                   | 0           |
| Qcache_inserts                                | 0           |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes                          | 0           |
| Qcache_not_cached                             | 391         |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache                       | 0           |
| Qcache_total_blocks                           | 1           |
| Queries                                       | 2237        |
| Questions                                     | 2           |
| Select_full_join                              | 0           |
| Select_full_range_join                        | 0           |
| Select_range                                  | 0           |
| Select_range_check                            | 0           |
| Select_scan                                   | 0           |
| Slave_heartbeat_period                        |             |
| Slave_last_heartbeat                          |             |
| Slave_open_temp_tables                        | 0           |
| Slave_received_heartbeats                     |             |
| Slave_retried_transactions                    |             |
| Slave_running                                 | OFF         |
| Slow_launch_threads                           | 0           |
| Slow_queries                                  | 0           |
| Sort_merge_passes                             | 0           |
| Sort_range                                    | 0           |
| Sort_rows                                     | 0           |
| Sort_scan                                     | 0           |
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates                       | 0           |
| Ssl_accepts                                   | 0           |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits                       | 0           |
| Ssl_cipher                                    |             |
| Ssl_cipher_list                               |             |
| Ssl_client_connects                           | 0           |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates                      | 0           |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth                          | 0           |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode                           | 0           |
| Ssl_default_timeout                           | 0           |
| Ssl_finished_accepts                          | 0           |
| Ssl_finished_connects                         | 0           |
| Ssl_server_not_after                          |             |
| Ssl_server_not_before                         |             |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits                        | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses                      | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode                        | NONE        |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows                   | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_size                        | 0           |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts                    | 0           |
| Ssl_sessions_reused                           | 0           |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries                | 0           |
| Ssl_verify_depth                              | 0           |
| Ssl_verify_mode                               | 0           |
| Ssl_version                                   |             |
| Table_locks_immediate                         | 241         |
| Table_locks_waited                            | 0           |
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 0           |
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 0           |
| Table_open_cache_overflows                    | 0           |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used                         | 0           |
| Tc_log_page_size                              | 0           |
| Tc_log_page_waits                             | 0           |
| Threads_cached                                | 2           |
| Threads_connected                             | 1           |
| Threads_created                               | 3           |
| Threads_running                               | 1           |
| Uptime                                        | 376259      |
| Uptime_since_flush_status                     | 376259      |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: We need your query and your tables to tell you which column to index.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the new table has indexes. If not set indexes

Answer (score 0):

Searching 31 million rows without index on one of the columns does indeed take a while to process.
It has to sequentially search each row, and with 31 million rows that takes a while.

Make sure that you at least have a primary-key and an index an every column you use to select/where query about.

What is the structure of your table/data? And which query do you use to select the rows?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use LOCAL** to specify the full path. Instead use just:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.ext'
```

this will look to c:/programdata(hidden)/mysql/mysql-server5.6/data/[your-schema]/file.ext

(This path can also be verified in 'Server Status' Tools listed under Data Directory.)

Why this works I don't know, but it's the difference between 4milx40  table loading in 22 secs vs. hanging indefinetly. Thus, worth the time to copy your file into that directory.

*Running MySql56, Windows8*